# How to write elegant perl code without ref

Tags: perl, oop, refactoring

Help me code this scenario better. Let's say I have a baseclass named "car", and two derived
classes named "Ferrari" and  "Chevrolet". Now I have an new class named "ParkingLot", which should know what the car it is operating on, to customize the lot-size and other attributes.

Now back to the problem. The current codebase that Iam working on is very matured, and it's complete written in Perl OOPS. The "ParkingLot" constructor will always be passed with the car object (instantiated much before this) as an argument. The code(Parking Lot) uses this argument, does a ref on object pointer to find whether the class is "Ferrari"/"Chevrolet" and does some very specific operations based on the car Type. This example, I would say is a "tip of the iceberg" and these kind of code is littered everywhere throughout the code making it more unmaintainable.

Tommorow, if I want to add a new car, that my parking Lot should support, then it's becomes a nightmare to check for references all through the code and do the changes manually. What would you do  to rework the code to make it more elegant and maintainable?

Comment: This kind of type checks instead of polymorphism is exactly what the Anti-If Campaign struggles against.

Comment: Look at the Ferarri. Now back to me. Now at the parking lot. Now back to me. The Ferrari is now a Chevrolet.  I'm on a horse.

Comment: @Ether - get off your high horse, please. And into the Lamborghini.

Comment: Uggh. So what you're saying is it uses blessed references, not Perl OOP. Think about it: does a parking lot need to know what kind of car is going to be parking there? No, right? Somebody failed in analysis. Since OOP is tolerated at your shop, you should really try improve the polymorphism--*if* decades of misunderstanding OOP hasn't made the process to overwhelming. Then just fix the code and don't worry about "elegance", because you're literally polishing a *turd*.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, don't be anti-if--just don't try to do with if what indirection is supposed to gain you.

Comment: @Axeman: exactly; metaphorically speaking, all the parking lot cares about is *properties* of the car: "mass", "width", "length", not its explicit type/brand.

Comment: @Ether, agree. There were two sides of this: practical and theoretical. Theoretically, a parking lot ought to hold parking spaces, which ought to gain behavior from the general concept of a space. A car-sized space should be understood by the Lot object. The car, should be gain behavior from the general concept of a 3-dimensional object (although 2-dimensions might be enough). The car can then give its dimensions or hunt around querying dimensions from the spaces. But practically, it sounds like it's way past doing design.

Comment: @Axeman: that's exactly what the Anti-If Campaign is about. Not getting rid of ifs, but getting people to use polymorphism. http://www.antiifcampaign.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the first comment on the question alluded to, what you want here is polymorphism.  Let the car decide how the car should behave rather than making the parking lot keep track of the behaviors of every kind of car out there.  e.g., Instead of this:

```
package Car;

package Ferrari;
use base 'Car';

package Chevrolet;
use base 'Car';

package ParkingLot;

sub add_car {
  if (ref $car = 'Ferrari') {
    $self->park_ferrari;
  } elsif (ref $car = 'Chevrolet') {
    $self->park_chevrolet;
  } else {
    die "Unknown car model!";
  }
}
```

do this:

```
package Car;

sub park {
  # park a generic Car
}

package Ferrari;
use base 'Car';
sub park {
  # take the Ferrari for a spin before parking it
  $self->drive_fast;
  $self->SUPER::park;
}

package Chevrolet;
use base 'Car';
# No sub park defined, so it just parks like a generic Car

package ParkingLot;

sub add_car {
  $car->park;
}
```

Now the ParkingLot just needs to know that it has a Car and the Car knows how it should `park`, so you can add as many new Car subclasses as you like without ever having to modify ParkingLot.

(Note that the above is Perl-like pseudocode, not real, runnable Perl code.  Many details were deliberately omitted.)

Comment: If I read the OP correctly, the issue is not whether the cars know how they ought to behave (e.g., `park`). Rather, it's that the *parking lot* needs to behave differently, depending on the kinds of cars it contains (e.g., `turn_on_security_cameras`).

Comment: @FM: Even in that case, it would be better to base the decision on some (potentially polymorphic) attribute of the car, such as `$car->price` or `$car->requires_security_cameras`, instead of listing off specific class names in the decision logic. It's the same principle as my answer, even if it might change some of the details of how to implement it.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably the ParkingLot is differentiating between the kinds of cars for a reason - for instance, likelihood of being stolen may differ between the two.  For every distinction ParkingLot makes, try to figure out what property of car (or lack of such property) that distinction is based on and give car or its subclasses those properties instead of deciding based on class.

As a temporary measure, give Chevrolet a I'm-a-Chevy property and Ferrari an I'm-a-Ferrari property and test those.